# Need help getting Cycles to match Eevee brightness

Tags: cycles-render-engine

[image]

[image]

[image]

Pic 1 is Eevee

Pic 2 is Cycles at exposure of 1

Pic 3 is Cycles at exposure of 5

Note that the backgorunds are of similar exposure in 1 & 2, implying that while the 3rd may be nice and bright, that's only because the exposure is overkill. That actual background/world color is fairly close to black.
**Side note**: I assume it's a 2.8 bug but the option to change the energy of the light disappears when you switch to cycles.

Comment: The devs know about this and the light intensities for Eevee will be adjusted to match better with cycles in some future 2.8 build. But expect some differences nonetheless, they are very different engines.

Comment: Oh ok, that's good to know.